# Disambiguate record update with DuplicateRecordFields

Tags: haskell, records, ambiguous-call

I'm using the DuplicateRecordFields (+OverloadedLabels) extension, and I've run into a situation where I can't figure out how to disambiguate in a record update.

Here is a simplified example:

```
data A = A { name :: String }
data B = B { name :: String }

combine :: A -> B -> A
combine a b = a { name = name b }
```

Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

I answered in one of the previous questions about `-XDuplicateRecordFields` that currently GHC doesn't infer type of record field from its argument:

- [Silly duplicated record fields error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44714711/silly-duplicated-record-fields-error/44716184#44716184)

What you can do now is to specify type of `name` extractor explicitly, like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}

data A = A { name :: String }
data B = B { name :: String }

combine :: A -> B -> A
combine a b = a { name = (name :: B -> String) b }
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can mechanically use `getField` from `GHC.Records` to disambiguate, like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}                                                                                                                                                         
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

module DRF where

import GHC.Records (getField)

data A = A { name :: String } deriving Show
data B = B { name :: String }

combine :: A -> B -> A
combine a b = a { name = getField @"name" b }

{- in ghci

Prelude DRF> a = A "Alice"  
Prelude DRF> b = B "Bob"    
Prelude DRF> DRF.combine a b
A {name = "Bob"}

-}
```

References:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/8693a3/usefulness_of_duplicaterecordfields/dw3fe8u/
- https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-Records.html

Answer (score 1):

You could match the name from a pattern:

```
data A = A { name :: String }
data B = B { name :: String }

combine :: A -> B -> A
combine a B{name = nb} = a { name = nb }
```

I'm not a fan of `DuplicateRecordFields` though. Why not instead go [the lens route](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4/docs/Control-Lens-TH.html#v:makeFields)?

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, FlexibleInstances, FunctionalDependencies #-}

import Control.Lens
import Control.Lens.TH

data A = A { _aName :: String }
makeFields ''A
data B = B { _bName :: String }
makeFields ''B

combine :: A -> B -> A
combine a b = a & name .~ b^.name
```

Comment: With `-XNamedFieldPuns`, we can also write `combine a B{ name } = a{ name = name }`.

Comment: @danidiaz _can_ we do this? Well, if you say so. IMO we _shouldn't_, at any rate; `{ name = name }` looks utterly confusing. All these extensions are unidiomatic hacks within the old record system that just doesn't work well this way. When `OverloadedRecordFields` will properly work via the `HasField` class and magic-hash syntax, that will be a different pair of shoes, but until then I'd stick to what the lens library has to offer.